# Is Zoom listening when screensaver is active?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, microphone, zoom.app

I've just noticed that when screensaver activates macOS shows a little orange circle in the upper right corner. It's a sign that something is used, usually a microphone. I went to look what that was and saw this:
[image: this is fucked up]
What is going on? Does Zoom start listening when the laptop is left unused? How to disable this?

Comment: Is Zoom open when it appears?

Comment: Yes Zoom is open but there's no active calls.

Comment: Then it's probably just poor programming on Zoom's part. You can close it if you'd like to be sure.

Comment: I wouldn't ask if it was listening all the time. In that case I would never keep it open unless I need to call. But activating with screensaver is suspicious behavior. Considering fact that Zoom had been creating serious security and privacy issues before I don't know what to think.